# Understanding the interaction between the oar and water

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, propulsion

[image]

I don't think the propulsion of boats using oars results from the water "pushing" the oars. I understand that momentum is conserved, but in terms of forces, what happens exactly during the interaction between the oar and the neighboring water that makes the boat move forward?

During a brief interaction time $\Delta t$, the oar pushes on the water with a force $\vec{f}_{oar}$, and the water reacts back with a force $\vec{f}_{water}=-\vec{f}_{oar}$.

I can't really see how this last force propels the boat.

Comment: *I can't really see how this last force propels the boat.* Can you please elaborate on why not? This force vector has a horizontal component in the direction the boat is moving.

Comment: @G.Smith The reason I believe this force doesn't contribute to the motion of the boat is because I see it as a static reaction; the water provides this reaction because the oar is pushing on it, the same way a wall would react if we push it. $\vec{f}_{water}$ is not acting over a distance, even though it has a component along the direction of motion.

Comment: If you don’t think that the force of the water on the oar is propelling the boat, what do you think *is*?

Comment: @G.Smith The body of the rower is the one providing the thrust, the same way a spring would thrust forward when pressed against a wall and then released; here, the water acts as a sort of wall that lasts for a very short time.

Comment: The water would not push on the boat if the rower didn’t push on the water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say in the comments:

> "The reason I believe this force doesn't contribute to the motion of the boat is because I see it as a static reaction; the water provides this reaction because the oar is pushing on it, the same way a wall would react if we push it."

When you push against a wall, that doesn't need to be static.  You can push off against a wall and generate acceleration.  You can push off against the ground and generate acceleration.

Even though the ground has an equal and opposite reaction, that opposite reaction is acting on the ground, not on the person.  The same applies with the oar.  You push the water, the water pushes back; but only one of those two forces is actually acting on the system you want to move (the boat/oar system), so you generate net acceleration.

Comment: So the water acts as sort of starting block, or wall, against which the oars push, and it's really the body (muscles) of the rower that is providing the thrust.

Comment: @Hilbert Yes, and you need something to push against if you actually want to generate movement (as per the conservation of momentum).  That's why in space you have to exhaust fuel; the only thing to really push against has to be stored with the ship.

Answer (score -3):

The water pushes the oars.

The oars push on the boat through the rowlocks.

The rower pushes backwards on the boat and forwards on the oars, controlling the angle of the oars but with no propulsion effect.

It all happens at the same time, so if you prefer to list them backwards it's OK.

Comment: *The oars push on the boat through the rowlocks.* If the rowlocks were the cause of the propulsion, then how do [rafts](https://www.google.com/search?q=raft&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ5OTrh9WS8hz7e-aWSLWOjeDdG8Q:1572468775727&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigrLDW7sTlAhWvShUIHdeJDUoQ_AUIEygC#imgrc=8tvi5iMe9cnH6M:) advance without rowlocks?

Comment: Rafts and canoes need two hands on the paddle.  Think of one hand as the rowlock if it helps.  The rower is not now providing two balanced forces - one on the craft and one on the oar.  The rower now has to add a new pair of forces,  one on a different part of the oar, turning it, the other propelling the craft.

Comment: @DrC You don't need two hands on the paddle, it's just much easier to deal with.  The rower pushes the oars _backwards_ which puts a forward force on the rower.  The rower is secured to the craft in such a way that they don't fly forward, and instead push forward on the boat so that the rower stays still in the boats reference frame.  This is what pushes the boat forward.

Comment: @JMac my reference to two hands was a response to Hilbert asking about a raft.